# substrings and the Go garbage collector

Tags: string, go, slice, idioms

When taking a substring of a string in Go, no new memory is allocated.  Instead, the underlying representation of the substring contains a Data pointer that is an offset of the original string's Data pointer.

This means that if I have a large string and wish to keep track of a small substring, the garbage collector will be unable to free any of the large string until I release all references to the shorter substring.

Slices have a similar problem, but you can get around it by making a copy of the subslice using copy().  I am unaware of any similar copy operation for strings.  What is the idiomatic and fastest way to make a "copy" of a substring?

Comment: This is kind of a shortcoming of Go. It should be possible to use make(string,foo[x:y]) for this.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type String struct {
    str *byte
    len int
}

func main() {
    str := "abc"
    substr := string([]byte(str[1:]))
    fmt.Println(str, substr)
    fmt.Println(*(*String)(unsafe.Pointer(&str)), *(*String)(unsafe.Pointer(&substr)))
}
```

Output:

```
abc bc
{0x4c0640 3} {0xc21000c940 2}
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution result in two copies of the substring being made?  One for the conversion to []byte, and another for the conversion back to string?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. However, the byte slice is a temporary.

Comment: And there is no guarantee that the compiler might replace this call with a noop in the future.

Answer (score 1):

## Since Go 1.17 (March 2022)

There is a function to create a copy of a string, which will copy the underlying data to a new location:

```
strings.Clone(s)

// Use this if you want to extract only a few substrings of a big string
subString := strings.Clone( bigString[5:10] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there are a couple ways you can do this without creating two copies of the data you want.

First is to create the `[]byte` of the substring, then simply coerce it to a `string` using `unsafe.Pointer`. This works because the header for a `[]byte` is the same as that for a `string`, except that the `[]byte` has an extra `Cap` field at the end, so it just gets truncated.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    str := "foobar"
    byt := []byte(str[3:])
    sub := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&byt))
    fmt.Println(str, sub)
}
```

---

The second way is to use `reflect.StringHeader` and `reflect.SliceHeader` to do a more explicit header transfer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    str := "foobar"
    byt := []byte(str[3:])
    bytPtr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&byt)).Data
    strHdr := reflect.StringHeader{Data: bytPtr, Len: len(byt)}
    sub := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&strHdr))
    fmt.Println(str, sub)
}
```