# Can this type of golang string slicing leak memory in underlying byte array?

Tags: arrays, string, go, memory-leaks, slice

Can golang string slicing like `buf = buf[n:]` cause memory leak in the underlying byte array?

If so, is it possible to get any information (like capacity, or base memory address) about the underlying byte array, in order to verify the leak?

Please see sample code below:

```
var buf string

func push(s string) {
    buf += s
    if len(buf) > 3 {
        buf = buf[len(buf)-3:] // can this line leak memory in underlying byte array?
    }
    fmt.Printf("buf=[%v]\n", buf)
}
```

[Run it on playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ad2_j2eGQh)

Comment: strings are immutable, so this just allocates a new string every time.

Comment: @jimb is there a clear reference about string slicing always allocating a full new string? So far, I have found this: "In Go, a string is in effect a read-only slice of bytes." https://blog.golang.org/strings

Comment: Slicing does not make a new string. But assigning the slice back to buf does.

Comment: I am actually not sure about this anymore. Maybe the string's bytes do end up hanging around...

Comment: @jimb So is it safe to assume there should not exist an underlying array which grows indefinitely in this case?

Comment: @Everton: it's safe to assume and easy to test. Just run your `push` in a loop with gctrace on. On my system it keeps a stable 4MB heap.

Comment: @JimB Great, thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909917/substrings-and-the-go-garbage-collector

Comment: @ZanLynx assigning back will create a new string variable, but this variable will still point to the underlying string from which text was sliced. `small := bigString[0:1]` will keep the whole of bigString in memory (not garbage collected), since it is referenced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this example can't cause a memory leak, since you need to allocate new strings each time you call `push`. It's possible that some bytes will be kept around at times to reduce allocations, but how that works is an implementation detail that shouldn't be taken into consideration.

If you're thinking of a similar situation which can arise when you assign a result of a slice operation, but never append. There's no leak per say, as long as you understand the semantics of slicing.

```
s := make([]byte, 1024)
s = s[1000:]
fmt.Println(s, len(s), cap(s))
```

This example will leave the first 1000 bytes allocated, but inaccessible. The answer to this is simple, don't do that. It's not hard to avoid, and if you do need to ensure that you've released the underlying array, use `copy` to move the bytes to a new slice.

This works the same with strings:

```
s = s[1020:]
// may leave the first 1000 bytes allocated
```

This is again fairly easy to see what's going on, and avoid. If you're using huge strings, you're often better off using `[]byte` anyway, where you have better control over allocation, and can copy the bytes when needed.

Comment: Thanks for this: "it's safe to assume and easy to test. Just run your push in a loop with gctrace on. On my system it keeps a stable 4MB heap. – JimB"

Comment: Still, I wonder if holding a reference to `s[i:j]` keeps `s` in memory? For example in Java `s.substring(i,j)` was holding to `s` data until Java 8.

Comment: @kostya: yes a single slice can keep the bytes alive as expected, http://play.golang.org/p/H6zQ0fMi-g, but that's not what this example was doing. I'll add a note about that though.

Comment: @JimB, this is quite interesting question. I will try to write down an alternative answer.

Answer (score 3):

A result of applying slice expression to a string in `p := s[i:j]` is a string. As far as I can tell the Go language specification (https://golang.org/ref/spec) doesn't specify that `p` will be backed by the same memory as `s`.

However it looks like in Go 1.6 and earlier versions a live reference to `p` will hold `s` from being garbage collected. This might however change in the future versions of Go.

An interesting fact that in Java `String.substring` method was implemented in the same way until Java 8. In Java 8 however `substring` returns a copy.

Back to your example. The following line actually creates a new string instance every time you call `push` function:

```
buf += s
```

The old instance of buf gets garbage collected. So your example is not affected by the problem described above.